# how can i make my document similarity from single matrix checking faster?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

I am trying to find document similarity from a large set of articles(460 files containing 4000 rows each). But doing `cosine similarity` is taking a lot of times to compute.

I can't use python libraries of sklearn or scipy. So I have tried to implement `raw tf-idf vectorizer` and `cosine similarity`. The vectorizer gives me a list of lists.

The matrix looks like this:

```
[[0.0,0.0,...…,0.35480,0.0,0.0],[0.0,.....]]
```

My code:

```
def computeTFIDFVector(document):
    tfidfVector = [0.0] * len(wordDict)

    for i, word in enumerate(wordDict):
        if word in document:
            tfidfVector[i] = document[word]
    return tfidfVector

def cosine_similarity(vector1, vector2):

    dot_product = sum(p*q for p,q in zip(vector1, vector2))

    magnitude = math.sqrt(sum([val**2 for val in vector1])) * math.sqrt(sum([val**2 for val in vector2]))

    if not magnitude:

        return 0

    return dot_product/magnitude


duplicates=[]
count=0
for i in range(len(tfidfVector)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(tfidfVector)):
        count=count+1
        clear_output()
        print(count)
        similarity=cosine_similarity(tfidfVector[i],tfidfVector[j])
        duplicates.append((i,j,similarity))
```

Now, the expected results are okay but it is taking like eternity to calculate. any suggestion how to make it faster?

Comment: Can you use a `DataFrame`? Their vectored implementations may speed this up significantly.

Comment: Thank you :) i will try it.